# What is the sense of defining several services in single WSDL file

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I understand it makes sense to exposes the same functionality (interface in WSDL 1.2, portType in WSDL 1.1) under different endpoints (ports in WSDL 1.1), depending on underlying transport protocol (definined by the binding). But what is the sense to put definitions of different services into a single WSDL? Especially, if each service exposes only a single operation?

For instance see the following WSDL file: http://seekda.com/cache?uri=http://score.itsc.uah.edu/services/catalog/SCOOPCatalogServices.wsdl&type=xml

WSDL1.2 specification mentions that *"WSDL 1.1 supports having multiple services in a single WSDL file. This has caused confusion amongst users."*. They resolve it by allowing *"multiple services, where each MAY be of a different service type."*. What does it mean -- of different type here?

Maciej

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the sense of defining several services in a single WSDL file?

The same sense, why you would define multiple interfaces with different operations in an object-oriented language: to modularize your service.

In theory I could pack all methods into one interface but since I want separation of concerns in my application I use different interfaces. Especially I want my Service Interfaces to correspond to back end implementations.

But important to remember: These services share types! Therefore it is very convenient to put it all into one WSDL.

Hope that's an acceptable reason ...

Comment: Very reasonsable. BTW, types can be shared in external file to be imported by seperate WSDL files, so I do not consider keeping all in a single file as a significant benefit.

Comment: Sadly when generating clients from different wsdls its a pain to keep the shared types even when correctly encapsulating in correct files. especially if you are overriding packages

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I found the WSDL at http://score.itsc.uah.edu/services/catalog/SCOOPCatalogServices.wsdl.

This is unusual. I've seen multiple bindings for a given port type, perhaps one for SOAP 1.1 and one for SOAP 1.2; but I don't think I've ever seen this pattern of one port type per operation.

There's a problem with the WSDL, according to XMLSpy. The `<soap:operation/>` are missing their `soapAction` attributes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your check. In fact it seems also quite strange to me. I'm curious if it is not standarized then if there is any set of the best practices for defining a service and whether there is a online validator that check whether WSDL file is both syntactically correct and conform to the best practices.

Comment: I don't know about any free ones. There are several commercial ones. All I had to do was open the file in XMLSpy and it told me the problem immediately.